# How to let a slave notify master?

Tags: android, multithreading, mutex

I would like to notify the UI Thread about a change event from a slave thread so the UI Thread could update the view. For a one execution things went well such as  :

```
public Class MainActivity extends Activity{

private final Object mutex = new Object();
private String[] data;
private boolean flag = false;


            //UI Thread
            synchronized(mutex)
            {
                try {
                    mutex.wait();                       
                    if(!flag){
                        adapter = new PlayListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row_item, data);              
                        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.playlist_listView);        
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        flag=true;
                    } else {
                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.addAll(data);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       

            //Slave thread
            While(true){
                 //Waiting for an event to occur in order to update data
                 //change data
                 synchronized(mutex){
                         mutex.notify();
                 } 
            }
   }
```

But then when I tried to make the UI Thread loop infinitely and wait for slave's notifications, the program did not work :

```
//UI Thread
    while(true){
            synchronized(mutex)
            {
                try {
                    mutex.wait();                       
                    if(!flag){
                        adapter = new PlayListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row_item, data);              
                        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.playlist_listView);        
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        flag=true;
                    } else {
                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.addAll(data);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
   }
```

I tried in the first place to change the view from the slave thread and discovered that this is prohibited in android so i tried then to use a handler thread but things did not go well as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way to do this with threads, you can try using IntentServices and a third party library like EventBus to communicate with your activity when it is done.

Check http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/

If you really want to do it in the Main UI you can use an AsyncTask instead.
Check this table to work with concurrency in Android https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DNU.png